# Move element with position relative and negative margins

Tags: html, css

In the example the ▼ must be got down for 50px, but it didn't happen.
Why didn't it work?

The jsfiddle example is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Valdemar/xs8m4jgb/).

```css
.notice {
  position: absolute;
}
.notice .pointer {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: -50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="notice">
  Some text(No matter)
  <div class="pointer">▼</div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you want to move something down 50px, a better way of doing it is transform: translateY(50px);

Answer (score 2):

In your example `position: relative;` takes no effects there, you can remove it to see.

You should use `top`, `right`, `bottom`, `left` to work with `position: relative;` for spacing.

Example:

```
.pointer {
  position: relative;
  bottom: -50px;
}
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zyf01kja/)**

That will move `.pointer` down `50px` relatives to its original position in the content flow.

If you do:

```
.pointer {
  margin-bottom: -50px;
}
```

That will move the next siblings up `50px`, which I don't think is what you want.

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6xjvvxkh/)**

Read this excellent article - [The Definitive Guide to Using Negative Margins](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/07/the-definitive-guide-to-using-negative-margins/) from Smashing Magazine. That explains it in great details.

Comment: yeah. But when I use margin-top with a negative value, it doesn't move it down. Why so?

Comment: @SUPIRRRR In general negative margin-top will move the element upwards, remember the following siblings follow the direction too.

Answer (score 2):

In short terms, **margin-bottom** influences the distance to the **next item** and **margin-top** the distance to the **previous item**. More details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-bottom

That is why margin-bottom can't move the arrow under the text "Some text (No matter)". It's not its role. You need to use ***margin-top*** or ***top***.

For a better understanding I have added another element to your code (after the arrow) and have assigned one class and background to each DIV.

HTML code:

```
<div class="notice">
  <div class="first">Some text(No matter)</div>
  <div class="pointer">▼</div>
  <div class="other">Other text</div>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
.notice, .first, .pointer, .other {
    padding: 10px;
}

.notice {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.first {
    background-color: green;
}

.notice .pointer {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: -30px;
    background-color: aqua;
}

.other {
    background-color: red;
}
```

===>>>  [Here a short demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUFv6.gif)  <<<===

Note: Run the code and use <kbd>F12</kbd> key (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>) to open Developer Tools and modify "margin-bottom" value.
For more informations about Developer Tools search on YouTube "Better CSS Coding & CSS Debugging with Developer Tools".

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution: https://jsfiddle.net/xs8m4jgb/1/

```
.notice .pointer {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your comment, can you elaborate what you want.

Comment: you want that the .pointer div to be outside of .notice div? like this: https://jsfiddle.net/xs8m4jgb/6/

Answer (score 0):

Your code will move the element up, because you're setting a negative margin-bottom.

If you want to move it down, there are several options, either use

```
transform: translateY(50px); (probably best solution)

top: 50px;
```

or

```
margin-top: 50px;
```

depending on your use case, and how you want it to behave in relation to it's parent.

Here's your fiddle, edited with the different versions:
https://jsfiddle.net/xs8m4jgb/3/

Comment: Heh, yeah. But when I use margin-top with a negative value, it doesn't move it down. Why so?

Comment: @SUPIRRRR A negative value on margin-top moves it upwards, not downwards

Comment: Because you have to imagine the margin as a space inserted between the elements. A margin-top: 20px would be a space of 20px inserted between the previous element and this one, therefore pushing the element down. A margin-top: -20px would create 'negative space', therefore pulling the element up.

Answer (score 0):

You should do some reading on CSS.

In order for something to "go down" you don't put a negative value. "-" Doesn't mean "down".

If you want distance between two elements stacked on each other, you must specify what value should be put between those elements.

Margin simply means "margin" (or distance between two elements, to be literate).

So in your case, since the pointer is inside the notice-class - You should specify a margin-top of the pointer.

```
.notice {
    position: absolute;
}
    .notice .pointer {
        position: relative;
        margin-top: 80px;
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xs8m4jgb/4/

Comment: Ok. But what if I wanna go out from the block? E.g. move an element to outside of the block

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean - But technically speaking - You just put the HTML elements next to each other:

`<div class="notice">Some text(No matter)</div>
  <div class="pointer">▼</div>`